# Firefox high virtual memory consumption

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, memory, performance

I am using Firefox 73.0 (64 bit) on Ubuntu. I was very happy with that until a few weeks.

Today, Firefox is taking too much of the available memory and make my system almost unusable. I have browsed the FAQ and made all proposals to reduce the memory. However, after a fresh restart and only 6 tabs and 5 add-ons, there is still a child process that takes 26.5G on virtual memory while Firefox Task Manager does not display that much memory (see screenshots).

How can I reduce the memory consumption of Firefox ?

Thanks a lot

[image: Htop]

[image: Firefox Task Manager]

Comment: Virtual memory isn’t physical memory. What you see is normal.

Comment: I know it is not physical memory but still, the system is slowed down when Firefox ran. I though the virtual memory was the most relevant measure in that case. 
I am also astonished by the number of child processes displayed by Htop.

Comment: Those are threads, not processes.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox allocates lot of virtual memory when using [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly). More details: Firefox [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1615988)
uBlock Origin [bug report](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uBlock-issues/issues/994)

You can ignore this or do the following:

1. Disable firefox extension(s), for example: uBlock Origin
2. about:memory -> Free memory -> Minimize memory usage